# Unable to identify some C# syntax for translation to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, porting, code-translation

I'm translating some example code line by line from C# to VB.NET.

The lines which confuse me looks like this:

```
[Kernel(CustomFallbackMethod = "AddCpu")]
```

I see in the code that these lines appear just before the method declaration:

```
private static void
```

What kind of line appears before a method declaration? Or is it a continuation of the last? I hope this is obvious to a native C Sharper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an [Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726029/attributes-in-c). It's a way to mark up code that can be used at runtime or compile time.

I would google VB.NET and Attributes. You can read some passages here on [O'Reilly](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/excerpt/vbnut_8/index1.html)

Your example would be converted to:

```
       <Kernel(CustomFallbackMethod:="AddCpu")>
```

Be sure to use `_` if you decide to put it on the line before your method.

Comment: the _ is no longer needed for line continuation in the latest version of VB.NET.