# What do square braces mean when placed before a class or member definition?

Tags: c#

Can somone explian what the square brackets in the following code do?

```
public interface IType : IEditor
    {
        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Genre ID
        /// </summary>
        int GenreID { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Genre name
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Unique System name")]
        string Name { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Url Genre safe name
        /// </summary>
        [DisplayName("Unique Url Safe name")]
        string UrlSafeName { get; set; }

        #endregion

    }
```

Comment: They keep the VB-ers out of our code base! But seriously, you find them around attributes and array declarations: `int[]`

Comment: The first Bing result for "what square brackets in C# do" is [MSDN documenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3hd7ste.aspx) on uses of square brackets in C#, including their use as attributes (the use you are showing).  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726029/attributes-in-c-sharp) is a good explanation of attributes.

Comment: How on earth is this closed as "not a real question"? It's the first Google result for "c# square brackets before method definition" and answered what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 4):

Attributes. See the reference article below.

[C# Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/

Answer (score 4):

They are applying [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx) to the property

Comment: I was wondering about how to reward people. I am use to expert exchange where I award points. Didnt see that option in Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

It is a syntax for applying attributes.

For more details check this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

See this page on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3hd7ste.aspx