# Preceding class declaration C# syntax like [SomeType (someArg1, ..., someArgN)]

Tags: c#, class, syntax

I'm new to C#. I've encountered such syntax:

```
[Node (false, "Texture/Texture Split")]
public class TextureSplitNode : Node 
{
    ...
}
```

or another example from System.Type:

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComDefaultInterfaceAttribute(typeof(_Type))]
[ComVisible(true)]
public abstract class Type : MemberInfo, IReflect, _Type
{
    ...
}
```

What do these preceding class declaration syntax constructions like `[SomeType (someArg1, ..., someArgN)]` means? Have they specific name?

Comment: These are called as attributes in c#. Check this documentation :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: This is an Attribute :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722303/what-do-square-braces-mean-when-placed-before-a-class-or-member-definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called [attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfz783fz(v=vs.110).aspx). They add metadata information to the language element (e.g. class, method or parameter) they are applied to.

[Metadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcd8txaw(v=vs.110).aspx) id non-executable information that describes the code.