# MVC route attribute square brackets

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I got the following code inherited from another developer an I am trying to understand it,what do the `square brackets []` stand for?why do some have 'HttpPost' and some 'HttpGet'

```
namespace webService.Controllers.Scheduler
{
    public class testbedsController : EntityController<testbedsService, testbeds>
    {
        testbedsService p = new testbedsService();
        [Route("api/testbeds/")]
        [HttpPost]
        public testbeds AddOrUpdate(testbeds testbedsInformation)
        {
            try
            {

                return p.AddOrUpdate(testbedsInformation);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {                
                throw new Exception(e.ToString());
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Its an [Attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346/net-what-are-attributes)

Comment: whats the significance of the square brackets around it?is there one or its just syntax?why do some have 'HttpPost' and some 'HttpGet'

Comment: That's just how the compiler knows that its an attribute (Metadata applied to the method). And [HttpGet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpgetattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) and [HttpPost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httppostattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) are filter attributes that determine if the method can be called as a get or a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square brackets denote a C# "attribute". They enable specifying additional data about something such as a method. See more info here: [Attributes in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726029/attributes-in-c-sharp)

The `HttpGet`, `HttpPost`, and `Route` attributes (among others) can specify the following:

1. The URL that you use to call the MVC action method
2. The allowed HTTP methods for the MVC action method

In this particular case:

- `[Route("api/testbeds/")]` --> This specifies that the URL for this action is `api/testbeds/`, so you would access this via `http://my-server/api/testbeds/`.
- `[HttpPost]` --> This doesn't specify a URL, but it specifies that only the HTTP "POST" verb is allowed (so not GET, PUT, DELETE, etc.)