# Will the C# attributes affect C# execution or the output?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Syntactically I understand how C# attributes are applied (i.e. denoted in square brackets []). **But it is not obvious what effects adding attributes actually has.**

For instance:

- Are attributes meant to be a type of commenting?
- How are these attributes handled by the C# compiler?
- Will these C# attributes change the C# program execution in any way?

Comment: No these are not used for comments. Usually these are used to annotate methodes, classes, etc. To perform analysis and automate tasks, like reflection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attributes in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726029/attributes-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4):

Attributes are not comments; they are classes that get added to the metadata of "things" in C#. By "things" I mean classes, properties, methods, etc.

An attribute absolutely *can* change the execution of a program... if something uses Reflection to read and act on the attributes. For example; the `[DataMember]` attribute will allow a `DataContractSerializer` to include that member in a serialized object. The `[Export]` attribute will be picked up by MEF code as a plugin.

There are many other examples and you can also create your own.
For far more information about attributes see: [Attributes in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726029/attributes-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are a powerful construct that can indirectly affect the code execution. You can inspect self or other classes using Reflection and change behaviour based on the presence of certain attributes.

Take a look at the c# programming guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/